"docker attach" hangs
I have this Dockerfile:
# Use an official image with CMake and GCC pre-installed
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set environment variables to prevent interactive prompts during package installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install necessary tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
cmake \
git \
wget \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the entire project into the container
RUN mkdir -p /app/data

COPY . /app

# Set the working directory to the project root
WORKDIR /app

# Create a build directory, configure, and build the project
RUN mkdir -p build && \
cd build && \
cmake .. && \
cmake --build .

VOLUME /app/data

# Set the default command to run the application
CMD ["./build/App"]

and this docker-compose YAML file:
  version: '3.8'

  services:
    app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
         - ./data:/app/data
      working_dir: /app
      stdin_open: true  
      tty: true

When I'm running docker-compose up --build it just prints out
Attaching to app-1

and nothing else.  I also have a screen shot showing the same thing.
What could be the problem?

Your app does not seem to be producing any output. Try logging something in the beginning to stdout/stderr and build and run again.
